# Cannot open .xls file downloaded using asp .net application

Tags: asp.net, download, webforms, ms-office, xls

I had created an asp .net web application that reads data from database, store the retrieved data in an excel sheet and download the excel sheet . All this happens in a single button click . All these steps work fine and i'm able to download .xls file . When I try to open this file using MSExcel 2007 I'm getting following warning message .[image]

If i click yes, I will be able to open this file . However, I don't want my users to do this every time they open their file . Can someone tell me how to avoid this warning message? Following is my source code .

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EMS_SMSConnectionString"].ToString()))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from accessories", con);
                // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                    // to open file prompt Box open or Save file
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=mridul.xls");

                    Response.Charset = "";
                    System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
                    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                    byte[] myByteArray = enc.GetBytes(dr["AccessoriesName"].ToString());
                    Response.BinaryWrite(myByteArray);
                    Response.End();
                }
```

Comment: user have to cancel the security warnings in Word

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use Use Microsoft's OOXML SDK: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx.

edit:
reference to MSDN article that exaplain it:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/03/11/excel-2007-extension-warning.aspx